# Получение серийного номера терминала

Tags: консоль, com-port

Есть терминал который подключается через com порт, необходимо как то узнать его серийный номер, есть готовые программы в которых реализованы эти функции, а как на самом деле это работает не понимаю.

Comment: о каких программах вы говорите?

Comment: Программы спецефические, и в открытом доступе их нет,  например tlvedit.